# Browser displays 'Apache is functioning normally' when I enter 'http://you/' in the location bar

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, virus, apache-http-server, trojan

I am on a Mac and when I enter `http://you/` in the location bar, it displays  'Apache is functioning normally' no matter which browser (Safari, Firefox, Chrome) I am using.

Is this normal? Or could it be that my computer is hacked in some way and is now acting as a server for the hackers?

EDIT:
I originally wanted to go to the youtube.com, but entered `http://you/` by accident and found out this strange behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but it may be that your network settings include a default search domain (something like your ISP or company's domain name).  The way this works is that if you have a search domain of "myisp.net", and you type "you" anyplace the system expects a domain name, it'll try "you.myisp.net" as well as just "you".  To check this, open a command line and try running the command `host you`; if it replies with something like "you.myisp.com has address 55.55.55.55", this is what's going on, and it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I have just opened the `Terminal` and entered `host you` and it replied: Host you not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)

Comment: Entering `ping you` in `Terminal` tells me that it resolves to `you.com.hk` and IP address is 218.189.220.102

Comment: Now I will assume it's the ISP who has done some sort of smart configuration on their DNS server that allows this to happen. But this reason is not quite convincing because I tried to enter `you` on my desktop PC and it does not display the `Apache is functioning normally` message in any browsers (IE, Firefox, Chrome). Both my Macbook and Desktop PC are behind a Buffalo router that connects to the cable modem provided by the ISP.

Comment: Some more data: you.com.hk also resolves to 218.189.220.102 for me; 218.189.220.102 is apparently a web host at Hutchison Global Communications in Hong Kong, hosting a [stack of domains](http://bgp.he.net/ip/218.189.220.102#_dns).  If I browse http://218.189.220.102/, I also get "Apache is functioning normally" (presumably it's a default page for queries that don't match any hosted domain names).

Comment: It's ok, as long as it's not some malware running on my Mac. It should be fine. Many many thanks for your help.

Comment: It mostly seems like you have com.hk as a search domain, but then I don't know why `host` doesn't resolve it that way, nor why the PC doesn't have the same search domain.  Anyway, it doesn't look malicious or dangerous to me, just a bit strange.

Answer (score 1):

This seems unusual. I just looked in an OS X 10.6 VM and nothing showed up by default when going to `http://you/` in Safari. You may want to check to see if Web Sharing is enabled in System Preferences. Go to `System Preferences > Sharing`, and see if `Web Sharing` is checked in the list on the left side of the window. If the box is unchecked, then the default Apache installation is not running, and something else has put that page there.

[image: osx_websharing]

`you` is also not a normal address to access the local machine. Check your [hosts file](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA27291?viewlocale=en_US) (`/private/etc/hosts`) to see if there is an entry for `you`, and whether that points to your local machine (`127.0.0.1`) or to some other server.

Comment: I just opened the `Terminal` and entered `ping you` and then it resolves to this IP 218.189.220.102. But the strange thing is that, I have checked my hosts file and there is no entry named `you` that points to 218.189.220.102.

Comment: I have also checked that the `Web Sharing` is not ticked in the `System Preferences > Sharing`.

Comment: I forgot to say that the ping also tells me that it resolves `you` as `you.com.hk`

Comment: My problem is kind of solved, it's possibly caused by some configuration of my ISP's DNS server. Thank you so much for your reply.